# Unix shell script for server alerts

Tags: shell, ping

Below is my shell script which is written in another x to find the health of server y. ( I have not written in server y because there is no functionality of getting mails)

```
 #!/bin/bash
target=10.9.34.52
count=$( ping -c 5 $target | grep icmp* | wc -l )
if [ $count -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "The Tomcat Dev server GMP_Dev_Tomcat_cvgrhegmpd003 with ip address 10.9.34.52 is DOWN Please check your server ASAP" |  mail -s " Dev Tomcat Server Status" Cahndraprakash@xxx.com
else
   echo "The Tomcat Dev server GMP_Dev_Tomcat_cvgrhegmpd003 with ip address 10.9.34.52 is UP and WORKING"

fi
```

I am not getting any alert. I have added my `shell` script to `crontab -e` which runs every 1 min. But if I run the script `./scriptname.sh`, I do get mails (I was checking when my server was up).

Comment: Since it's running as a cronjob, does it send any email to the user who has this cronjob? I would also start by changing all commands (`wc`, `mail`, `grep`, `ping`, etc) to use the absolute paths. If a script works from the command line but doesn't from `crond` then the difference is usually with the environment.

Comment: @JoelDavis yes it does send the mail ( when I did a test run) ... But im not getting any alerts when its actually down. I cant give the absolute path. I just want to check if the server is alive. As of now my program pings to the target server and checks if there is reply..If not then it should mail ( but it doesn't)

Comment: Your problem is the grep... actually the pipes....

Comment: @Braiam then what should be ?

Comment: Not sure what was meant by pipes but if the user themselves is getting the email instead of you then that means `$count` is always not zero. I would update the paths. There's also a more straightforward way of doing this. Check [this](https://dpaste.de/V8t7) out.

Comment: Also, just as a general idea. YMMV but I usually have better luck when I test for narrowly defined success and save the "catch-all" (the `else`) for notifying you when there's an error. That's because there are generally many different ways something could fail (making it hard to anticipate and need a catch-all) but only one way it could succeed.

Comment: Instead of counting output lines, use `if ping -q -c 5 $target >/dev/null`. `ping` sets its exit status based on whether it received all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

If it's failing in cron where it works in shell, it's usually an environment issue, as Joel mentioned.

In your cron, try logging the script output by appending `>> /home/myuser/myscript.log` to the end of your cron line, then read the file after your cron runs.

You may find a lot of entries like `-bash: ping: command not found`, in which case you need to use the absolute paths in your script (ie `/bin/ping` instead of `ping`). You can use `which [command]` to find the absolute path for a command.